# Entity manager cant find custom repository class

Tags: orm, oauth-2.0, doctrine, silex

help me please, i am learning to use silex framework and i would like to integrate silex with dflydev(OAuth2). but have an error with doctrine orm provider:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'OAuth2Test\Server\RepositoryOAuthClientRepository' not found in /var/www/html/firsttest/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Repository/DefaultRepositoryFactory.php:68 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/html/firsttest/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Repository/DefaultRepositoryFactory.php(50): Doctrine\ORM\Repository\DefaultRepositoryFactory->createRepository(Object(Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager), 'OAuth2Test\Serv...') #1 /var/www/html/firsttest/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/EntityManager.php(698): Doctrine\ORM\Repository\DefaultRepositoryFactory->getRepository(Object(Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager), 'OAuth2Test\Serv...') #2 /var/www/html/firsttest/src/OAuth2Test/Server/Controllers/Token.php(22): Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager->getRepository('OAuth2Test\Serv...') #3 [internal function]: OAuth2Test\Server\Controllers\Token->OAuth2Test\Server\Controllers{closure}() #4 /var/www/html/firsttest/vendor/symfony/http-kernel/HttpKernel.php(153): call_user_func_array(Object(Closure), Array) #5 /var/w in /var/www/html/firsttest/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Repository/DefaultRepositoryFactory.php on line 68

...

```
├── src
│   ├── app.php
│   ├── OAuth2Test
│   │   └── Server
│   │       ├── Controllers
│   │       ├── Entity
│   │       ├── Repository
│   │       └── Server.php
│   └── routes.php
```

autoload :

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {"OAuth2Test\\": "src/OAuth2Test/"}
}
```

app.php :

```
$app->register(new DoctrineOrmServiceProvider, array(
    'orm.proxies_dir'           => __DIR__.'/OAuth2Test/Server/Entity/proxy',
    'orm.em.options'            => array(
        'mappings'  =>  array(
            array(
                'alias'                         => 'OAuth2Test',
                'type'                          => 'annotation',
                'namespace'                     => "OAuth2Test\Server\Entity",
                'resources_namespace'           => "OAuth2Test\Server\Entity",
                'path'                          => __DIR__."/OAuth2Test/Server/Entity",
                'use_simple_annotation_reader'  => false,
            ),
        ),
    ),
));
```

my entity:

```
namespace OAuth2Test\Server\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM; 

/**
* @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="OAuth2Test\Server\Repository\OAuthClientRepository")
*/
class OAuthClient extends EncryptableFieldEntity{
```

My Repository:

```
namespace OAuth2Test\Server\Repository;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;
use OAuth2\Storage\ClientCredentialsInterface;

class OAuthClientRepository extends EntityRepository implements ClientCredentialsInterface{
```

Controller(Token.php):

```
$controllers->post("/token", function() use($app){

    $clientStorage = $app['orm.em']->getRepository('OAuth2Test\Server\Entity\OAuthClient');
    $userStorage = $app['orm.em']->getRepository('OAuth2Test\Server\Entity\OAuthUser');
    $accessTokenStorage = $app['orm.em']->getRepository('OAuth2Test\Server\Entity\OAuthAccessToken');

    $server = new \OAuth2\Server([
        'client_credentials' => $clientStorage,
        'user_credentials'   => $userStorage,
        'access_token'       => $accessTokenStorage,
    ], [
        'auth_code_lifetime' => 30,
        'refresh_token_lifetime' => 30,
    ]);

   $app['oauth_server']  = $server;

   return app['oauth_server']->handleTokenRequest(OAuth2\Request::createFromGlobals())->send();
})
->bind('grant');

return $controllers;
```

maybe someone can help me please.

pd: sorry for my bad english!.

Comment: Did you get a solution for this in the end?

Comment: for while I solved it using PDO https://bshaffer.github.io/oauth2-server-php-docs/storage/pdo/.